# @AttributeOverride - inherit some attributes as default values

Tags: java, jpa, mapping

There is denomination field in embeddable Money class.

```
@Column(scale = 4, precision = 20)
private BigDecimal denomination;
```

When I use Money class several times in some entity class, I have to override column name via @AttributeOverride annotation.

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "denomination", column = @Column(name = "premium_amount")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "currencyCode", column = @Column(name = "premium_amount_currency")) })
private Money premium;

@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "denomination", column = @Column(name = "discount_amount")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "currencyCode", column = @Column(name = "discount_amount_currency")) })
private Money discount;
```

This way overrides also (scale = 4, precision = 20) attributes to default values. Is it possible to inherit these attributes by default or I have to specify they every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible.

It has nothing to do with JPA, but with annotations:
If you evaluate an annotation during runtime, e.g. `Column.scale()`, you can't tell if someone set the value for an attribute explicitly or if it is was not included in the declaration.

So from the view of the JPA provider both definitions are equal: `@Column()` and `@Column(scale = 0, precision = 0)`. And as the provider can't distinguish both definitions, it will always use the value returned from `scale()` - in your case the default value `0`.

So you will have to set these values explicitly - or use some code generation tool that automatically derives the appropriate annotations (although I don't know which one would do this out of the box).

Comment: Got it! Thanks for detailed answer)